# How to select group parent ONLY when tapping the selection box

Tags: android

I have the following activity in my app

[activity with groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bg4V.png)

every group in the activity represents a meal, and it has child that represent the extras. the problem is that the only way i can select a group is by taping the little selection box at the right side of the group, and i want to be able to select it by tapping any part of the group (its name, for example).

also, the expand list that should be displayed when tapping a group parent, isn't showing. any idea is appreciated.

here is the code of the controller of that activity:

```
/**
 * Adapter for each product displayed in the activity
 */

public class ListaProductosAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context ctx;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> food_category;

    protected boolean checkboxEstabaChequeada = false;
    ArrayList<Producto> productos;

    public ListaProductosAdapter(Context ctx, HashMap<String, List<String>> food_category, ArrayList<Producto> productos) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.food_category = food_category;
        this.productos = productos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return productos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return food_category.get(productos.get(i)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return productos.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int parent, int child) {
        return food_category.get(productos.get(parent)).get(child);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int parent, int child) {
        return child;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int parent, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_layout, parentView, false);
        }
        TextView parentTextview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parent_txt);
        TextView parentTextview2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parent_precio);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding:

```
parentTextview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    getGroup(parent);
  }
});
```